# Fresh react-native project npm start fails

Tags: node.js, macos, react-native, npm

I have a react-native project which i was running on expo, so using npm start and it was working fine.  I made no changes to the project and returned and it stopped working.  I created a new project and I am getting the same error.  How is the error log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamkatz/.npm/_logs/2017-12-05T05_45_41_605Z-debug.log

I went to the link supplied and it only gave info for people who are on linux and as I am on OSX it never helped.

npm is 4.6.1

react-native start seems to work fine.

Significantly i realised I updated my OSX the night before, i hope that helps lead to the answer

Comment: I am not familiar with using that script on React Native. If you are on OSX, you should be running `react-native run-ios`.

Comment: I am using expo on top of react native so the correct way to start a project is npm start.  I cant actually remember what this problem is but it all seems to be working now.  Maybe it was just an OS issue

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I am not familiar with expo, glad its working now.

Comment: me too, you should check it out though, its really great